# C++ - Changing value of Member of a class through member functions

Tags: c++11

I have a class that has a std::vector member used to store objects of an external class.

```
class Example {
  private:
    std::vector<OtherClass> list_of_things_;
}

class OtherClass {
  public:
    void ChangeName(std::string name);
  private:
    std::string name_;
}
```

Through my code I want to change some of the OtherClass objects stored in this list_of_things_, so I use two functions in my Example class:

```
std::vector<OtherClass> RetrieveObjects() {
  std::vector<OtherClass> result;
  std::vector<OtherClass>::iterator it;
  for (it = list_of_things_.begin(); it != list_of_things_.end(); ++it) {
    if (some condition is met) {
      result.push_back(*it);
    }
  }
}
```

And then in another function inside Example I call this like:

```
std::vector<OtherClass> objs = RetrieveObjects();
std::vector<OtherClass>::iterator it;
for (it = objs.begin(); it != objs.end(); ++it) {
  it->ChangeName("new name");
}
```

Now, this is in principle working, but only when I check the names from the objs variable, this does not change the objects inside list_of_things_ which is my main intention.

Have I actually do a copy of the objects instead of retrieving the same objects in list_of_things_? If that is so, why? Have I made some other mistake? Should I be using pointers? I'm new to C++ and still finding my way around.

Here you can find a test code that runs:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class OtherClass {
  public:
    OtherClass(std::string s) : name_(s) {}
    std::string GetName();
    void ChangeName(std::string name);
  private:
    std::string name_;
};

std::string OtherClass::GetName() {
  return name_;
}

void OtherClass::ChangeName(std::string name) {
  name_ = name;
}

class Example {
  public:
    Example(std::vector<OtherClass> l) : list_of_things_(l) {}
    void ChangeNames();
    void WriteNames();
  protected:
    std::vector<OtherClass> RetrieveObjects();
  private:
    std::vector<OtherClass> list_of_things_;
};

std::vector<OtherClass> Example::RetrieveObjects() {
  std::vector<OtherClass> result;
  std::vector<OtherClass>::iterator it;
  for (it = list_of_things_.begin(); it != list_of_things_.end(); ++it) {
    if (it->GetName() == "Name") {
      result.push_back(*it);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

void Example::ChangeNames() {
  std::vector<OtherClass> objs = RetrieveObjects();
  std::vector<OtherClass>::iterator it;
  for (it = objs.begin(); it != objs.end(); ++it) {
    it->ChangeName("new name");
    std::cout << it->GetName() << std::endl;
  }
}

void Example::WriteNames() {
  std::vector<OtherClass>::iterator it;
  for (it = list_of_things_.begin(); it != list_of_things_.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->GetName() << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  OtherClass oc = OtherClass("Name");
  OtherClass oc2 = OtherClass("None");
  OtherClass oc3 = OtherClass("Name");

  std::vector<OtherClass> v = {oc, oc2, oc3};

  Example ex = Example(v);
  ex.ChangeNames();
  ex.WriteNames();
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only make changes to the local `objs` vector, which is *a copy* of the `list_of_things_` vector. Since you never write the changes from the copy back to the member, they are lost when `objs` is destroyed.

The easiest way to fix this is to not call `RetrieveObjects` inside `ChangeNames`, but instead work on the `list_of_things_` member directly:

```
void Example::ChangeNames() {
    std::vector<OtherClass>::iterator it;
    for (it = list_of_things_.begin(); it != list_of_things_.end(); ++it) {
        it->ChangeName("new name");
        std::cout << it->GetName() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The reason you get the copy can be found in the signature of `RetrieveObjects`:

```
std::vector<OtherClass> Example::RetrieveObjects()
```

The return value here is a new `std::vector<OtherClass>` object. If you instead want a reference to an existing class object, the signature changes to:

```
std::vector<OtherClass>& Example::RetrieveObjects()
```

Note the additional `&` on the return value. This is different from languages like C# and Java, where certain complex types are always passed by reference.

An implementation of `RetrieveObjects` that returns a reference to the member vector would be:

```
std::vector<OtherClass>& Example::RetrieveObjects() {
    return list_of_things_;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

If I wanted a vector of references, should I use:
    std::vector<OtherClass&> 
with the '&' inside?

Comment: @EDL Vectors of references don't really work that well, as references are immutable. You are probably better off with a vector of pointers in such a case: `std::vector<OtherClass*>`. Pointers are syntactically a bit more tricky to handle than references though, so you might need to do some reading first if you are unfamiliar with them.

Answer (score 0):

It it already been said you modify copy of your vector, and that is why your main vector stays the same.
You can go this approach if you use smart pointers instead of simple objects.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<OtherClass> OtherClassPtr;
```

then replace all OtherClass uses to OtherClassPtr so that you have
std::vector of OtherClassPtr objects, and so on. You'll have to create them sligtly differently ( std::make_shared() ) and instead of . you use ->
But then after you copy several objects and modify them they will be modified everywhere, because you only copy pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> Have I actually do a copy of the objects instead of retrieving the same objects in list_of_things_?

Yes. You create a new vector, holding copies of the original values, which match your selection criteria.

> If that is so, why?

```
std::vector<OtherClass> Example::RetrieveObjects() { // returns a new vector
  std::vector<OtherClass> result;
  std::vector<OtherClass>::iterator it;
  for (it = list_of_things_.begin(); it != list_of_things_.end(); ++it) {
    if (it->GetName() == "Name") {
      result.push_back(*it); // The content of *it is copied to the new element of result.
    }
  }
  return result; // do return a new vector, holding copies of originals
}

void Example::ChangeNames() {
  std::vector<OtherClass> objs = RetrieveObjects(); // a local object with auto lifetime
  std::vector<OtherClass>::iterator it;
  for (it = objs.begin(); it != objs.end(); ++it) {
    it->ChangeName("new name"); // acts on local object, class members are intact
    std::cout << it->GetName() << std::endl;
  }
} // local object is gone with any changes it holds
```

> Have I made some other mistake? Should I be using pointers?

Instead of trying to make a criteria based selection from `list_of_things_` first and then performing some action on selected values, I'd try to search and act on original `list_of_things_` simultaneously in one pass.